# cocos2d-js: Custom touch handler in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I'm developing in cocos2d-js but I want to handle sensitive functions (e.g. IAP validations) in C++ before JS touch handling code is invoked.

Where is the place in C++ where JS `onTouchBegan:function` is called?
What is the best way to inject my custom code there?

My goal with just symbolic function names:

```
void XX::YY()
{
    if (isUnlocked() == true) {
         callJS("onTouchBegan:function");
    }
    else {
         showUnlockScene();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this elegant trick. Now all payment handling is kept isolated in C++:

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{
    ...
    EventListenerTouchOneByOne *l = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    l->setSwallowTouches(true);
    l->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event) {
        if (isUnlocked() == true) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
             showUnlockScene();
             return true;
        }
    };

    director->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(l, -1000);
    ...
}
```